# Why doesn't this field-separator regex allow me to extract the desired value?

Tags: awk

My input file `sumacomando` looks like this:

```
"firstName": "gdrgo",   "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John",   "lastName": "222",dfg
"xxxxx": "John",    "firstName": "beto",   "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John",   "lastName": "111","xxxxx": "John",
"xxxxx": "John",    "firstName": "beto",   "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John",   "lastName": "111","xxxxx": "John",
"xxxxx": "John",   "xxxxx": "John",    "firstName": "beto2", "xxxxx": "John","lastName": "555", "xxxxx": "John","xxxxx": "John",
"xxxxx": "John",   "xxxxx": "John",    "firstName": "beto2", "xxxxx": "John","lastName": "444", "xxxxx": "John","xxxxx": "John",
"firstName": "gdrgo",   "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John", "xxxxx": "John",   "lastName": "222",dfg
"xxxxx": "John",   "xxxxx": "John",    "firstName": "beto2", "xxxxx": "John","lastName": "444", "xxxxx": "John","xxxxx": "John",
```

I use this command:

```
awk -v RS="\n" \
    -v FS='firstName": "|",[^+]*lastName": "|",' \
    '{sum[$1]=$2;} {print sum[$1]}' sumacomando
```

which outputs:

```
gdrgo
111
111
555
444
gdrgo
444
```

but I expected this:

```
222
111
111
555
444
222
444
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is the data file really as sloppy with spaces after commas as what you show? Your field-separator regex is hard work reading — don't you think you should treat Awk with a little more respect? What do you think the middle term handles? You have `",[^+]*lastName": "`, which looks to me like a double quote, a comma, zero or more other characters that aren't a plus sign, then `lastName`, a double quote, colon, space, double quote. Have you simply printed out the fields (unambiguously) so you can see how Awk interprets your regex? (`for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) printf("%d:%d [[%s]]\n", NR, i, $i);`?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The input is somewhat irregular, and it's not clear what the purpose of array `sum` is, but to give you exactly what you're asking for:

```
awk -F'^.*"lastName": "|",' '{ print $2 }' sumacomando
```

The field-separator regex `'^.*"lastName": "|",'` matches everything from the start of the line up to `"lastName": "`, and after that by `",`, so that the 2nd field - `$2` - effectively becomes the content of the `lastName` field's associated value.